# Xcopy or Robocopy from Network folder to SharePoint(2013)

Tags: command-line, batch, sharepoint

I am trying to copy files from a network folder to a SharePoint folder. I have read/write permissions to the SP folder and can manually upload documents to it.

I was able to get the .bat to work 1 time but after that I keep getting the following log message:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Thu Sep 18 11:10:00 2014

   Source : \\WAPPRIB00001040\prod\output\HLS\
     Dest = \\departments.internal.ck.com@ssl\sites\hlsreports\HLS_Reporting\

    Files : TestFile.txt

  Options : /COPY:DATS /ZB /R:1000000 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

NOTE : NTFS Security may not be copied - Destination may not be NTFS.

2014/09/18 11:10:02 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Creating Destination Directory \\departments.internal.ck.com@ssl\sites\hlsreports\HLS_Reporting\
Access is denied.
```

Here is the .bat:

`robocopy \\WAPPRIB00001040\prod\output\HLS\ \\departments.internal.ck.com@ssl\sites\hlsreports\HLS_Reporting /ZB /SEC TestFile.txt >> \\WAPPRIB00001040\prod\output\HLS\Log.txt`

I would prefer to use Xcopy but it that doesn't want to work either. I switched to Robocopy because the log was a little more robust.

Greatly appreciate any input! I've been chewing away at this for the last week and have been all over the web to find a solution with no luck.

Comment: If Robocopy runs as your user, then you have to figure out why your user's access is being denied.  Does the target folder actually exist? Did it exist the first time you ran the batch (when it worked)?

Answer (score -1):

try copy:DAT the D = Data A = Attributes T = Time stamps

S = NTFS access control list (ACL) this should resolve the NTFS security error and assuming the item will get security from the destination folder anyway.